# Filtering STDOUT in Perl

Tags: perl, shell, stdout

I do this so that every message send out to `STDOUT` in my script is logged.

```
open(STDOUT," | tee $log") or die "Unable to open $log";
```

Is it easily possible to filter all the messages which are send out to the log ? Say substitution of a character ?

Comment: `open(STDOUT, "| perl -pe's/.../.../' | tee $log")`

Answer (score 2):

Not the way you're doing it, because what you're doing is sending *everything* to `tee` and `tee` is then printing what it's logging.

You could perhaps create a pipe that has a `sed` built in. But an alternative might be to write your own 'log_line' sub, that prints to a log file and stdout explicitly.

```
sub print2 {
    print {$output_fh} @_;
    print @_; 
}
```

And you could build in your own transforms.

You also have several modules to draw upon, such as `IO::Tee` and `log4perl`. If you're wanting to have different things going to `STDOUT` and your log, then it's probably worth looking at doing a more fully featured logging.